# Definition of homeomorphism w.r.t. subspace topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functions, differential-topology

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ be open and $f \colon U \rightarrow f(U) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a homeomorphism.

I think this means that $f(U)$ is not necessarily an open set but $f$ is an open map with respecet to the subspace topology of $f(U)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is this correct?

Now my question is, if $m=n$, why can we conclude that $f(U)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$? And why is this wrong in general for $m \neq n$?

Comment: Brouwer's "Invariance of Domain" theorem?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct: to say $f:U\to f(U)$ is a homeomorphism means that it is an open map with respect to the subspace topology on $f(U)$, so that does not automatically mean $f(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$

The fact that $f(U)$ is open if $m=n$ is a hard theorem, known as "[invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain)".  You can find a proof in many algebraic topology texts; for instance, it is Theorem 2B.3 of [Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html).

If $m\neq n$, there are very easy counterexamples.  For instance, the map $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $f(x)=(x,0)$ is a homeomorphism to its image but its image is not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.